# freed BST but still getting memory leak C

Tags: c, memory, malloc, binary-search-tree, free

I know there are tons of people asking this question, and I have looked through all the answers on those posts but still doesn't fix my problem. 
I'm trying to free the Binary search tree in C. I written the code for freeing the memory. Here are the code for Insert, createNode and freeNode:

**Insertion**

```
    Node *insertNode(Node *root, int value) {
    /*
        Insertion of node in Binary Search Tree. The new node must be added in the correct subtree (either left or right).
        If the value is less than the root value then it should be insert in the left subtree. If it's bigger then it should be
        on the right.
    */
    if (root == NULL) {
        //if this is the first node then return its value.
        root = createNode(value);
        return root;
    }
    //on the left subtree
    if (value < root->data) {
        //recurse down the left subtree
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, value);
    } else if (value > root->data) {
        //recurse down the right subtree otherwise.
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, value);
    }

    return root;
}
```

**Free tree**

```
void freeSubtree(Node *N) {
   if(N == NULL) {
       return;
   } else{
       freeSubtree(N->right);

       freeSubtree(N->left);
       N->right = NULL;
       N->left = NULL;
   }
       free(N);

}
```

**Create new node**

```
Node *createNode(int value) {
    //allocate space for the node.
    Node *newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

I don't know why there is still memory leaks since I have freed all the nodes. I can't see where I went wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Here are the memory leaks reported from valgrind 
[Valgrind memory leak error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1eC2.png)

Comment: How exactly do you know that you have a memory leak?

Comment: Those look okay to me, using eyeballs and not a compiler.  There are various minor improvements that could be made, but I see nothing critical.  So, the question becomes “how are you using this code?”  Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) that shows the leak.

Comment: The leaks come from two different call chains.  Do yourself a favour and include `-g` in (all) your builds — compile and link lines.  Then you'll get line numbers in the Valgrind output.  You're wasting Valgrind if you don't use `-g`.  Please show the code you're using to generate the leaks (that's the MCVE I asked for previously).  We shouldn't have to guess what sequence of operations you're doing.

Comment: I tried a `main()` function like this — with several variants on the numbers used and many runs with the random sequence — and never got any memory leaked: `int main(void)
{
    Node *root = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        root = insertNode(root, rand() % 53);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        root = insertNode(root, (13 * i + 7) % 47);
    freeSubtree(root);
    return 0;
}` — it is now crucial that you show exactly what you are doing.

Comment: PLo - make sure you are compiling with `-g` to generate a symbols (if using gcc) and post the `valgrind` output as text at the bottom of your question (indented properly by 4-spaces).

Comment: OT: regarding: `Node *newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));` 1)  in C, the returned type s `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the cast.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in the insert() functon, what happens if the 'value' is the same as the current node value

Answer (score 1):

I assembled this code based on what's in the question.  I've cleaned up your three functions, added the type definition, headers, a tree printing function, and a `main()` program.  I ran it under Valgrind numerous times, with different configurations in the `main()` program — different numbers in the multiplications, additions and modulo operations, and different sequences for the tree building, and building one tree instead of three, etc.  None of these induced a memory leak.

```
/* SO 5495-1700 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

static Node *createNode(int value);
static void freeSubtree(Node *node);
static Node *insertNode(Node *root, int value);

Node *insertNode(Node *root, int value)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        root = createNode(value);
    else if (value < root->data)
        root->left = insertNode(root->left, value);
    else if (value > root->data)
        root->right = insertNode(root->right, value);
    return root;
}

void freeSubtree(Node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return;
    freeSubtree(N->right);
    freeSubtree(N->left);
    N->right = NULL;
    N->left = NULL;
    free(N);
}

Node *createNode(int value)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

static void printValueIndented(int level, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        fputs("    ", stdout);
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

static void printTree(const char *tag, Node *root, int level)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    if (level == 0 && tag != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", tag);
    printValueIndented(level, root->data);
    printTree(tag, root->left, level + 1);
    printTree(tag, root->right, level + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    Node *root = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        root = insertNode(root, i);
    printTree("Sequence", root, 0);
    freeSubtree(root);
    root = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        root = insertNode(root, rand() % 53);
    printTree("Random", root, 0);
    freeSubtree(root);
    root = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        root = insertNode(root, (13 * i + 7) % 47);
    printTree("Computed", root, 0);
    freeSubtree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

One example run:

```
Sequence
0
    1
        2
            3
                4
                    5
                        6
                            7
                                8
                                    9
                                        10
                                            11
                                                12
                                                    13
                                                        14
                                                            15
                                                                16
                                                                    17
                                                                        18
                                                                            19
Random
4
    51
        24
            17
                16
                    7
            30
                32
                    31
                    41
                        34
                            36
                                39
                        45
                            43
Computed
7
    4
        1
        6
    20
        12
            9
            17
                14
                19
        33
            25
                22
                30
                    27
            46
                38
                    35
                    43
                        40
```

It is therefore unclear how your code is triggering a memory leak.  If you are still getting the leak, then you need to show the exact code that generates it (create an MCVE — [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and show the Valgrind output in your (updated) question.